# RAILS 5 app in production is not writing anything to logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, ruby-on-rails-5, passenger

We have a RoR5 multi threaded app that when deployed to production was writing to production log. But after 30 minutes, it stopped writing to the log. I am confused as to how this could happen. Without logs it is impossible to understand what is going on the production log. A restart of the app also exhibited the same behavior. Wondering if anyone has faced this issue before or what are the things I should look for?

App's cpu utilization, network in's out's is all normal. Database connections are same before and after deployment.

Comment: Will you please tell me which web server and application server you are using.

Comment: phusion passenger enterprise and mysql server

Comment: Just a few ideas: 1) production.log file may be chunked, so when the file exceeds certain size, a new productionX.log file may be created 2) you might not have enough space

Comment: sadly that is not the case here. The app seems to be stuck now, it is not functioning as expected. It is a consumer which consumes from amazon sqs queues..now the queues are just building up and no log file ..crazy time

Comment: @user2452057 I hope you do have Phusion Passenger with Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you do have Phusion Passenger with Nginx.
There are several things that you need to confirm
1.) Just write rails c and then use Rails.env to check the current environment.
If "production" then move to step 2

2.) Is your production.log file have the permission to write. check it using

> ls -l

3.) Also check Nginx logs to know what actually the problem is.